# show().parent().show() - What is going on here?

Tags: jquery

I don't understand what happens when you do a chain of .show()s like that. Nor did I write this code or have an idea of how to figure out what is happening here. Hence this question.

```
// Remove favorite category
        $(".FavoriteRemove").click(function() {
            var cat = $(this).parents(".Category");     //the parent of the clicked item is the category/bundle
            var catid = $(this).attr("catid");          //the id tag on the clicked item is the BundleID
            $.post($(this).attr("href"), function() {   //the href tag is the post URL for adding a favorite
                cat.remove();                           //here we remove the category/bundle

//*** WHAT IS THIS DOING? v
            $(".Category[catid=" + catid + "]").show().parent().show();
//*** NO THAT UP THERE ^
            if ($(".FavoriteCategories div").length == 0)
                $(".FavoriteCategories").hide();
            //bindCategories();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Can someone describe what this means? I am aware the target is class 'Category' with an attribute matching the ID but I don't understand what the chain of functions means.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First  [`show()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  the element with the class `Category`, and the `catid` attribute with value of the given variable.
- Then traverse up to its parent using the [`parent()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.
- Then  [`show()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  the parent.

"Showing" means setting its `display` style property from `none` to its initial (or default) value, like `block`.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you can directly "use" the return value of a function call without assigning the value to a variable. [Here is a stripped down example](http://jsfiddle.net/4QRFa/1/):

```
var john = {
    me: function() {
        alert('...John');
    }
}

var foo = {
    call: function() {
        alert('You called..');
        return this;        // <- note that an object is returned    
    },                      // (in this case foo itself but could be any object)

    callSomeoneElse: function() {
        alert('You called..');
        return john;       // <- note that an object is returned
    },

    me: function() {
        alert('...me');
    }
}

foo.call().me()
foo.callSomeoneElse().me()
```

---

Now to your method call:

If you have

```
$(selector).show()
```

then the selected elements will be shown. `show` returns again the set of selected elements (the same elements selected by `$(selector)`). This allows us to call another method on them: `parent()` selects (returns) the parent nodes of these elements (so we have a different set now) and the second `show()` operates on this new (parent) set (and returns the parent set).

So

```
$(selector).show().parent().show()
```

will show the selected elements and their parents.

---

The whole concept is called [**fluent interface**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and is achieved through [**method chaining**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fluent interface; I think that's the source of the confusion here.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Much more thorough than mine. +1

Comment: @patrick dw: I tried my best... but I needed half an hour for it ;) (non-native English speaker at work :D)

Comment: I never would have guessed *(non-native English)*. English is my only language, and I isn't so good at it. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".Category[catid=" + catid + "]").show().parent().show();
```

It will show (make visible) the element(s) with a class `Category` and a catid set to the variable *catid*, and it will show the parent element:

```
<div>
   <span class="Category" catid="1"></span>
</div>
```

In this case it would show both the span and the div.